# How to tell that class/struct is copyable using python bindings for clang tooling

Tags: python, c++, clang, libtooling

Our project is using clang python api to generate python bindings for C++ classes.
Right now we have a limitation that the copy will only be exposed if a type has an explicitly defined copy constructor.

I would like to change it to also declare a copy for a generated copy constructor - so I need to detect that somehow.

All the structs I care about are trivially copyable, so if I can only detect trivially copyable ones that is fine as well.

How could I tell that a struct I am at is copyable or trivially copyable?
I have `CursorKind.STRUCT_DECL` as my starting point.

Comment: So using Clang Python API I can do any C++ code AST traversing/inspection? Sounds great, always wanted to parse C++ from python!

Comment: Yep. there are a bunch of tutorials on youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what we ended up with.

a) Seems like from clang ast directly you can only ask if 'is_pod'
[cindex.py](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/281703e67ffaee8e26efef86e0df3e145477f4cb/clang/bindings/python/clang/cindex.py#L2332)

Not quite what I need since `pod` also implies no default constructor accroding to this [std::is_pod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod) [std::is_trivial](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod).

b) What we did is:

1. include the original file in a different tmp file that we generate and
   parse that.
2. in that file generate a specially named `enum <ClassName>_Traits` with `std::is_copy_constructible` for a class of interest.